# Op-amp overheating - Generating two variable voltages

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, potentiometer

I have a stereo potentiometer (10 kΩ) and a +5 VDC voltage (regulated by a 7805) with which I am trying to generate two "inverse" voltages, so at the same time one channel being high resistance and the other low resistance ie. channel one 5 V and channel two 0 V, or channel one 2.5 V and channel two 2.5 V. I hope you get it.

I then want to buffer these voltages with a TL072. The op-amp is overheating and I have a feeling that the power supply does not like what I do either. The load impedance is around 4.7 kΩ, which shouldn't be the problem. But what is?

This how I hooked it up:

[image: circuit]

Comment: Welcome! From where did you buy the TL072? Are they oscillating by any chance? They are unity gain stable, but still...

Comment: Why don't you use an inverting op-amp to get the negative rail.

Comment: They are Texas Instruments TL072s. How can I test for oscillation? I bypassed both power supplies with 100n X7R bypass caps.

Comment: Aren't you applying too high supply voltage to opamp? You are applying 34V whereas recommended is 30V max. What is the voltage connected to the potentiomenter? Hope it is lesser than the V+ of the opamp

Comment: Negative rail? You mean like a comparator? I already tried that but was not satisfied, but I forgot the reason why. You're right, I should probably work on that solution.
The TL072 says the maximum power supply is +-18V and the DC I apply is 5V., so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @linsensuppe0815, +/-18V is absolute max if I am not mistaken. We should use the opamp based on the recommended conditions.

Comment: @sai It depends on the exact part number, some versions have ROC of +/- 20V max.

Comment: @GodJihyo, yes, I missed that. It depends on the exact variant.

Comment: Anything else in the circuit you've not shown? Any capacitors across the op-amp supply pins? Any capacitors on the op-amp inputs or outputs?

Comment: An older type of TL07x has an absolute max supply of +18V and -18v but +15V and -15V max are recommended. They have new TL07xH ICs now with an absolute max of +21V and -21V and a recommended max of +20V and -20V.

Comment: Oscope the output. If you have genuine +-20 V TI ones, they should not be overheating. From where did you buy them? If Ali/ebay or similar, the risk of counterfeits are high.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a stereo potentiometer. I've built such a circuit on the breadboard just now and it works fine. Nothing's overheating. I've bought the op-amps in my "collection" directly from TI, though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLpkho.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

TL072 is bypassed with 1uF from both either supply rail to ground.

OA1 is a buffer. OA2 inverts the voltage with respect to 2.5V. So, as A goes from 0V..5V, B goes from 5V to 0V. That's what you wanted, right?

The resistors R2-R5 can come from a DIP-packaged 4-resistor array. Their value is not critical. 10kΩ..100kΩ should be fine.

Comment: Why C5? (half a microsecond with R3)

Comment: Thank you for providing the circuit! So R4 and R5 are for the biasing to 2.5V? What are C3 and C4 there for?

Comment: @DanielChisholm Can you explain what time constant you calculated? I know that capacitors like C5 in the feedback of an op-amp are for stability, but never knew which values are suitable.

Comment: R3*C5 = 484ns ("half a microsecond").  OA2 is set up as a voltage inverter with gain=1 (R2 = R3), but a a 22pF cap is paralleled with R3.... presumably to boost the frequency response of the feedback.  I wouldn't have put it there, but knowing @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica is no dummy he probably has a very good reason(s) that I am overlooking

Comment: It’s just a bit of compensation for stray capacitances on input. Will keep the circuit working if you replace the op-amp with something even faster. But for a TL07x that’s already good practice imho. Especially that I’ve said that the exact resistor value is no big deal but match is. TL08x, 100k resistor and poor layout and it may turn into a bell. So I’m conservative that way :)

Comment: C3 is so that a scratchy potentiometer doesn’t wreak havoc and to have AC power supply rejection. C4 is to maintain some semblance of PSR as well. The circuit may work without them, but that’s IMHO just good practice. It’s not something that will be sold in millions by penny pinchers, so an extra cap or two for reliability is no most desirable.

Comment: @DanielChisholm Half the time I still feel like a dummy reading what more experienced people share :) Not gonna feel any shame for it either. Just life. Either you acknowledge it or fantasize :)